# Can I split ceiling light wire to create a receptacle on ceiling?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, light-fixture, wire

I'm trying to install LED string lights (2 Watt x 15 bulbs) around the porch covered by permanent roof. But, it looks ugly if I run an extension cord on the wall from the outlet to the ceiling.

There are two light fixtures on the ceiling. Will it be permissible to split the wires from one of the light fixtures to make a receptacle on the ceiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split, no. Splice, yes, assuming the box has adequate space for the box fill with additional wires, or that you upgrade the box if needed.

Since you are adding a receptacle, you'll need to put a GFCI on the circuit or as the receptacle if the circuit is not already GFCI protected.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you follow @Ecnerwal answer instructions for adding GFI receptacle and do not advocate using the device pictured below, but I am showing it in case you are unaware of these devices. I have had a light fixture and cord plugged into one of these, in a covered outdoor location, for 15 years with no problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use these in the basement all the time:
[Socket extender with outlets](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Socket-with-Outlets-White-R52-01403-00W/100184555)
[image: picture]